# How can I repair the disk by command?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have NAS system which has 6 discs
/dev/sde3

I started Raid6 like this

```
$madam --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 
/dev/sdf3
```

Now my /dev/sdb3 is broken.

```
$mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.
```

Other discs is like this (example /dev/sda3)

```
$mdadm --examine /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 1ee2825d:c17b9791:b57012c3:b8ef186d
           Name : 7c6de3be:data-0  (local to host 7c6de3be)
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 28 23:29:28 2017
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 15618480752 (7447.47 GiB 7996.66 GB)
     Array Size : 31236699136 (29789.64 GiB 31986.38 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15618349568 (7447.41 GiB 7996.59 GB)
    Data Offset : 131072 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=130792 sectors, after=131184 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5deada26:04642eee:64b141dc:47f69f98

    Update Time : Mon Feb 26 19:33:48 2018
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 153967eb - correct
         Events : 691075

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

How can I start repairing drive /dev/sdb3??

---

Then I did this

```
 $mdadm /dev/md127 -r /dev/sdb3
```

and restarted linux.

Next,I want to do like this.

```
$mdadm /dev/md127 --manage --add /dev/sdb3
```

However there is no /dev/sdb3 anymore.
So I couldn't do this command.

How can slove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 6 disks, they should be available in `/dev` as `/dev/sda`, `dev/sdb`... `/dev/sdf`. So, unless your disk has failed -which is always an option- it should be visible as `/dev/sdx`. Then you could use a tool like `fdisk` or `parted` ot whatever, check for the existence of `/dev/sdx3`, label it accordingly if needed and then add it to the array.

Comment: Thanks I tried fdisk but there is no /dev/sdb or extra /dev/sd* It completely disappears , restarted a few times, but in vain. If I connect and reconnect cable it appears though, my server is physically isolated from me so I can't. Is there any way to re-scan SATA drives??

Comment: Your description points to a hardware failure, be it a not well seated SATA connector, a failed disk, bad cable, whatever. It's one of the cases that will most probably require physical access to the server from somebody competent enough not to make things worse.